# Как изменить заголовки окон в xorg?

Tags: linux, xorg

Здравствуйте.

Обычно, программа, отображаемая в окне, сама управляет заголовком окна. Это приводит к ситуации, когда заголовок окна содержит какую угодно информацию, кроме нужной: названия самой программы. Например, браузеры пихают туда названия текущих вкладок, терминалы - юзер@хост и т. д. В лучшем случае, название программы идет в конце длинной строки. Есть ли способ влиять на то, как устанавливаются эти названия во всех вкладках.

В манах программки wmctrl упоминаются такие понятия как "icon name (short title)" и "name (long title)". Может есть способ заставить быть тайтлом окна только icon name?

Спасибо.

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/626505/how-do-i-permanently-change-window-titles